# How to create a daemon thread in QT / Python

Tags: python, qt

How do I create a QThread in Python that automatically quits/terminates / is killed when the main thread exits?

In most libraries I've used this as simple as passing flag to the constructor when creating a thread.

Such a simple task and I've searched like 30 minutes to find an answer.